# write multiple where filtering in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multiple-conditions

how can i write a sql like this?

`$sqlNext = "select * from table WHERE (status='normal') AND (number = (select max(number) from table where number < 5)) LIMIT 1";`

in first step filter the result by `status` column, after that

search in rows with `number` value less than 5 in `status='normal'` rows.

in this sql first part of `AND`=>`status='normal'` IS NOT WORK

just send me max row with `number` value less than 5

Comment: You would need to have the `status='normal'` filter in the subquery as well, if i understand your question correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this what you're looking for?

```
select max(number), status from table WHERE status='normal' and number < 5
```